# When do we choose time as a categorical or continuous variable in longitudinal MLM?

Tags: categorical-data, multilevel-analysis

I understand that we can use time as a categorical or continuous variable in multilevel models (MLM). In which cases would it be better to use time as a categorical variable?

And how is the analysis of time as a categorical variable different from that when time is continuous variable?

Comment: Please spell out your acronyms. What is "MLM"? Can you say more about the situation, your data, your analysis, & your goals?

Comment: @gung I agree about spelling out acronyms (it's a comment I frequently make). Here, it seems pretty clear to me (and probably to you) that it means multilevel model. The OP seems to have vanished. So, I will edit the question for her.

Answer (score 1):

For time, as for any other continuous variable, if you categorize it you are forcing the times in one category to all be the same in the model and you are allowing jumps in the results at the borders in categories.

This rarely makes sense. The exceptions are when you have a strong *a priori* hypothesis about a specific time point. Even there, though, a spline of time might be better.

I wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@peterflom/what-happens-when-we-categorize-an-independent-variable-in-regression-77d4c5862b6c) taking a graphical look at what happens when we categorize an independent variable.

As the other answer points out, there are special things about time as an IV, but I don't think those relate to this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, time is always clearly ordered/ordinal - a time variable would never be unordered categories, i.e. nominal. If it is ordered categories that you can't or don't want to treat as continuous, then the choice of cutpoints between the categories becomes important. Maybe those cutpoints are substantively meaningful, either because you want to test that they divide before-and-after observations into groups with statistically significant differences, or because you've already done a separate cutpoint analysis and those cutpoints emerged as statistically significant breakpoints in a trend. Those are the only situations in which I think it makes sense to treat it as non-continuous. If you do treat it as ordered categories without any substantive or data-driven reason to do so, then someone is going to question the model dependence, i.e. would your findings change or go away if we happened to define the categories differently.

With regards to interpretation, the main difference is that time clearly correlates with almost everything and so its apparent effects are almost always just measurements of the effects of many other unobserved variables. Maybe time is capturing some maturation process of a sort - a unit-level autoregessive effect, I believe you would call it - or maybe it's proxying for other causal influences that are, for whatever reason, increasing in prevalence or frequency over time, and may or may not continue to increase. Thus, "the effect of time" is useful in terms of causal inference in a where-there's-smoke-there's-fire sense - the real question is always what is actually driving the change that is correlated with time.